# Web API - Can Windows Authentication and an API key be used on same call?

Tags: api, web-services, authentication

I'm new to web services and am creating HTTP services using .NET Web API 2.

The consumers of the services will be other applications, but in the future I foresee web applications (browsers, mobile apps) using them. The services simply serve data to the consumers (no create/update/delete).

All applications, including the API, are located on our enterprise intranet. Nothing outward facing.

I was told to use Integrated Windows Authentication for the services. Can an API key also be used on the same services to authenticate the application that is making the calls?

I'm not even sure doing this makes sense. Can the consuming application (i.e executable run on a server) send account info? My thought is that Windows Authentication isn't necessary and token authentication will suffice. Others have told me to use both. I'm not sure that's possible and haven't found anything showing me it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API key is a parameter passed to the service interface, so it can be passed with any type of auth on the backend.

But usually, and api key is used to determine whether a user is allowed to use a specific API. For example, if only a subset of users that have windows accounts are allowed to use the api, then maybe that might make sense, because, even if they could authenticate with their windows account, they could still be determined to be unauthorized by the fact that they did not pass a valid auth key.

That said, you could also do the same things with some kind of policy, for example, checking if the user has the correct role to call the api method. It makes more sense when you are giving people access to an api through the internet.